# Is it possible to overwrite cookie by another website

Tags: php, cookies, windows-8

I have set the cookie on my website like this
setcookie('src_from','',time()+60*60*24*2,'/');

but when i am doing inspect element, In cookie section of under my website its showing another website name in domain column.

This is strange, why this is happening i am not able to understand, Please help me to sort out this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you include elements from other sites (i.e. images, scripts) - these sites can send headers with cookie. And you can see cookies from another sites on this pages. But another sites can't see cookies of each other (and overwrite too) - because of policy of your browser.

Answer (score 0):

It can be possible but if you control those two websites/scripts.
In other cases it would be very hard to do that.
The thing is that you might haven't done it properly.
Try providing the domain name as a next parameter.
Or reload the site with using ctrl+F5 or clear all cookies in a browser.

Comment: Problem is that  my website cookie is overridding by another website on my client pc. Trying  to  provide the domain name it will resolve the problem?

Comment: I haven't got such a problem yet but please try it. Because now, it is not specified. In your case it seems like making difference.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a cookie expiration time in the past:

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()-60*60*24*2);
```

so you are actually removing the cookie - it's not overwriten by another cookie

Comment: Sorry,  it is  setcookie('src_from','',time()+60*60*24*2,'/');